# How do I get rid of the Places map

Tags: facebook

Theres a field called Places, with a map. I don't want it there. I've tried the suggestios but can't get it to go away

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about removing the map tile on your timeline profile, then do this:

- To the right of your "favorited" tiles, click on the arrow pointing down.
- Hover over the map tile and click the "Edit" icon (a pencil)
- Select "Remove from favorites"

When you refresh the page the map tile should be gone.